# Was Jesus' early church composed primarily of Torah-abiding Jews?

Tags: jesus, ecclesiology, early-church

> If he refuses to listen to them, tell it to the **church**. If he refuses to listen to the church, treat him like a **Gentile** or a tax collector. Mattews. 18:17 KJV

How to understand the word ἐκκλησίας in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly started that way.

> You see, brother, how **many thousands** there are among the Jews of those who have believed. They are **all zealous for the law**, 21 and they have been told about you that you teach all the Jews who are among the Gentiles to forsake Moses, telling them not to circumcise their children or walk according to our customs. 22 What then is to be done? They will certainly hear that you have come. 23 Do therefore what we tell you. We have four men who are under a vow; 24 take these men and purify yourself along with them and pay their expenses, so that they may shave their heads. Thus all will know that there is nothing in what they have been told about you, but that you yourself also live in observance of the law. 25 But as for the Gentiles who have believed, we have sent a letter with our judgment that they should abstain from what has been sacrificed to idols, and from blood, and from what has been strangled, and from sexual immorality.” 26 Then Paul took the men, and the next day he purified himself along with them and went into the temple, giving notice when the days of purification would be fulfilled and the offering presented for each one of them. -- (Acts 21:20–26, ESV)

Paul Barnett in is book on the beginnings of Christianity states:

> The boundaries for our study are, on the far side, the crucifixion of Jesus (dated to 33 [or 30]) and, on this side, Paul’s early westward missions (dated to ca. 48). The later marker was chosen since it “fixes” the historic beginning of the new faith becoming the province of Gentiles. For practical purposes, then, we are speaking about Jewish Christianity of the thirties and forties, a span of twenty years, more or less. Nothing hangs on absolute precision.
> --
> Barnett, P. (2005). *The Birth of Christianity: The First Twenty Years* (Vol. 1, p. 9). William B. Eerdmans Publishing Company.